# Am I at risk for giving my email, name and phone number to a scammer?

Tags: scam

I signed up in UFX using my email, name and mobile phone number. I immediately received a call from an unknown number, which was from an employee who tried to take my bank account information so he would supposedly help me to input my debit card on the site. Also during the call, using some communication tricks he managed to quickly acquire a few information such as If I have ever done a trade with my account before and approximately where I live. Of course, I didn't give him my bank account info at I immediately closed the phone, after realizing where this is going.

My questions:

1. Is my bank account at risk?
2. Can they use my voice as verification for other trades? (the "Yes scam" that I read about)
3. What more personal information is at risk?

Comment: Never, ***ever***, give personal information over the phone.  Next time this happens say you will be going into the actual location to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my bank account at risk?

Not directly. But the scammer can/will work to get a "foothold" using the information they have on you. You are also now clearly on the radar of a scammer and I would consider yourself at high risk.

> Can they use my voice as verification for other trades? (the "Yes scam" that I read about)

I sincerely hope not. If a company allows for verification of a trade with no account information or verification code or any sort of "multi-factor", It would be very concerning. You should check with the company and see what is required for a verbal verification. Also, "Yes scam" is a bit of a misnomer. Not a lot of "voice signature" based verification out there. If an attacker has your account numbers and calls into an automated hotline, it won't matter that it's a female voice saying "Yes" if you're actually a man. That's not checked for as far as I know in the vast majority of those systems.

> What more personal information is at risk?

They will try to leverage the information they have to get into your accounts. If they can get into any account, they will get more information and continue. They will also probably launch a Phishing scheme (don't click email links without putting them in virus total's URL check https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/url, at the very least. Ideally just don't click email links).

> What to do

Change your passwords. Do you have a password in the format of [Name][Date][symbol]? If so you don't have to be a hacker, someone can guess it in 100 guesses probably. Create a strong password (4, 4 letter words with a cap and 1 symbol or number is easy to remember and far more secure than 8 characters).

While you're changing your passwords, check for strange log in activity on your accounts. Notify UFX.